# @ManyToOne + delete operation leads to "not-null property references a null or transient value" error

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate-mapped data structures and there is an error when I try to delete it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TYPE")
public class Type {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private Type type;
}
```

When I try to remove Book object I got

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com....Book.type; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com...Book.type
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:645)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:846)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:842)
```

When I remove optional = false parameter I see that Hibernate deletes objects from TYPES tables.  Why it tries to remove type entities, if there is ManyToOne link from oposite side?
Thanks.

**upd:**
Collections of books is available in parent object. To remove it I use this code:

```
Information info = getInformationById(id);
        if (info != null) {
            getHibernateTemplate().delete(info);
        }
```

**upd2 (full hierarchy):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INFO")
public class Information {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INFO_ID")
    private Set<Details> details;
```

...
    }

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAILS")
public class Details {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "INFO_ID")
    private int infoId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DETAILS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Set<Books> books = new HashSet<Book>();
```

...
    }

Chain is: Info->Details->Books. Each book has a type, it is possible, that many books have the same type. I don't want to delete type entities, when I delete info objects.

Comment: Done. It is included into parent object Information, and I delete parent object.

Comment: Sorry, added full hierarchy to the end of the post.

Comment: BTW, the same error when I try to delete book objct directly.

Comment: Have you tried using `@ManyToOne(cascade = {}, optional = false)` for the `Book`->`Type` association? It seems it is somehow cascading deletes to `Type`. Can you see anything related in Hibernate logs? BTW, eager fetching is the default for `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Xavi, your solution with {} doesn't work, I get the same error. It is a cascade delete, but I don't understand why it is started. Many books could have the same type (@ManyToOne) why hibernate deletes type when I delete book?

Comment: Hah, it was my mistake. I have another Type item in Details class with Cascade type. So it was the reason of the problem.